# Audio is choppy/stuttering

Tags: sound

I am an extreme noob. I just installed ubuntu for the first time yesterday, and both online and offline audio is stuttering often. I read a forum that said to go into etc/pulse/default.pa and putting load-module module-udev-detect and adding tsched=0 then entering pulseaudio -k in the terminal but it didn't work. again, I am an extreme noob so please go easy on me lol. I have an hp pavilion 17-g121wm.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You haven't told us your release details, which tell us what software stack (and it's age) you are using. You told us your machine make/mode, which is rather useful for windows where kernel modules/drivers are geared that way (as the OEM does the packaging), however in GNU/Linux and Ubuntu the kernel modules are based on chipsets used inside machines, which can vary over the life of popular makes/model boxes. Details of your hardware can be obtained many ways, I find `lshw -C sound` easy to remember (list hardware of class sound, the driver= tells you module in use)

Answer (score 0):

I did further reading of forums and found the solution. It's wi-fi related, and quickly switching airplane mode on and then off right after start up does the job.

Comment: That is weird. Can you try going into Settings --> Sound and check if the Over-Amplification isn't turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue. I first watch this => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3Eyu4a1XD4 it didn't solve problem. but i kept all changes which are done according to video. then I enter following command,

```
$ sudo nano /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

it will open daemon.conf, then locate

> ;realtime-scheduling = yes

using arrow down/up and remove " ; " and change it to

> realtime-scheduling = no

then save it (press Ctrl+o then enter)(quit => Ctrl+x). finally, run following command or restart computer.

```
$ systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
```

it was done job for me. Good luck. :)